# non-English character not translating correctly in console app

Tags: c#

Environment: Visual Studio 2008 SP1

I have the following line in my text file:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\DATA.txt"))
{
  ...
  string textLine = "ist where [name]='Curaçao')"
}
```

Please notice the non-English character.

Whenever the **reader.ReadLine** gets to this point it turns it into a question mark in my console application.

Any ideas how to preserve that?

Comment: How are you declaring the reader? What encoding are you using for it? What encoding is the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an encoding issue - the `reader` is using a different encoding to the one the file is in.

Make sure both are using the same encoding.

`File.OpenText` will use the `UTF8Encoding` - if your file is in a different encoding, this may very well be the issue.

To specify an encoding, construct `StreamReader` with a constructor that takes an `Encoding` parameter:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\DATA.txt", 
                                               Encoding.GetEncoding(860)))
{
  ...
  string textLine = "ist where [name]='Curaçao')"
}
```

In the above example, I am using the Portuguese encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the charset in the reader. The console, however, doesn't support non-ASCII characters!